# Incorrect output of matrix in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix

I am writing a code to take a value and create a matrix with a size that allows for a pyramid of 1s to be made so the top one is at the x-1 element. For example, if the input was five, the output would be:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

The problem is the code is generating values that shouldn't be one, or it is not outputting the matrix the correct way.  I have tried adding a cout to the code where it defines some values as 1 and those are correct, so I believe that the problem is in the output. For example, an input of x will give

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        cout << "Matrix size:";
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        int arr1[2*x][x];
        for (int initialX=0; initialX<x; initialX++){
                for (int initialY=0; initialY<=((2*x)-2); initialY++){
                        arr1[initialX][initialY]=0;
                }
        }
        for (int set=0; set<x; set++){
                arr1[set][x-1-set]=1;
                arr1[set][x-1+set]=1;
        }
        for (int outX=0; outX<x; outX++){
                for (int outY=0; outY<(2*x-1); outY++){
                        cout << arr1[outX][outY] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This is my first time working with matrices in c++, so any help concerning matrices is appreciated. Also, if it's of any importance I'm using c++11.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: VLAs are non-standard C++, you should avoid using them even if they do work in your compiler.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please see this as to why you [should not use variable length arrays](http://ideone.com/1mcWo6).  Using `std::vector` and `at()` clearly demonstrates what the problem is.  There are a huge number of posts by persons using VLA's and issues with segmentation faults or bad output being produced that could be easily diagnosed if the usage of VLA's was stopped and instead, `vector` was used (with the additional `vector::at()` call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array dimensions need to be switched. Instead of

```
int arr1[2*x][x];
```

use

```
int arr1[x][2*x];
```

Because of that error, you are accessing the array out of bounds, which leads to undefined behavior.

Since VLAs are not standards C++, I highly recommend use of `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr1(x, std::vector<int>(2*x));
```

That will also initialize all the elements to `0` and obviate the need to write explicit code to initialize the array elements to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have swapped the index values for your set. Also, I wouldn't recommend using `set` as a variable name. Try this:

```
for (int i=0; i<x; i++){
    arr1[x-1-i][x]=1;
    arr1[x-1+i][x]=1;
}
```

When in doubt, try stepping through the code with a small value, like x=2.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int** CreateMatrix(int size);

int main()
{
    cout << "Matrix size:";
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    int** intArray = CreateMatrix(x);

    int max = (x * 2) - 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < x; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < max; col++)
        {
            cout << intArray[row][col] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int** CreateMatrix(int size)
{
    int max = (size * 2) -1;
    int** intArray = new int*[size];
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        intArray[index] = new int[max];

    int middle = size - 1;
    int low = middle;
    int high = middle;

    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < max; col++)
        {
            intArray[row][col] = (col == low || col == high) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        low--;
        high++;
    }
    return intArray;
}
```

Comment: This code has a memory leak, and demonstrates a prime example as to why one should use `std::vector` instead of dynamically allocated C-style arrays in C++.

Comment: The delete is simple. The question was more about how to create the matrix correctly.

    for (int row = 0; row < x; row++)
    {
        delete intArray[row];
    }
    delete intArray;